# How to copy the root folder using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script which displays the latest folder created and copies that folder.
The folder structure is like this

```
$localPath = c:\deployments\dates\codes\html5\users\admin
$DestinationPath = c:\project\html5\users\admin
```

and than inside admin folder we have other files and folders.
I would like to copy the latest deployments from localpath to destination path which would be replacing admin's content with new deployments

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $LocalPath | 
Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | 
Select-Object -Last 1 | Copy-Item -Destination $DestinationPath -Recurse -Force
```

The only confusion is to get the latest folder and copying the content of the root folder or the end folder and pasting it on to the destination

Comment: Why so complicated...? Why not `copy-item $localPath\* $DestinationPath -recurse -force`?

Comment: its because i need to copy from the latest folder . this is what confuses me alot. First sort the content on latest date, than copy the root folders content and than paste. I searched alot but could not find much information. I hope some one can help over here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply splitting into a couple of commands is a better approach:

```
$localPath = c:\deployments\dates\codes\html5\users\admin
$destinationPath = c:\project\html5\users\admin
$latestDir = $(get-childitem $localPath | sort lastwritetime | select -Last 1).FullName
Copy-Item "$latestDir\*" "$destinationPath" -recurse -force
```

Comment: i just ran your script, but it actually copies the whole of deployment folder, if you see in my question i need to copy the content of my root folder that is admin.

Comment: Your question says: `I would like to copy the latest deployments from localpath to destination path which would be replacing admin's content with new deployments`... I don't understand how this behaviour differences from what you've asked for, so please rephrase it if that's not correct. What is in `$localPath`? Files, directories or both?

Comment: localpath has folders and files, but i am interested in the roor folder and its content to get copied

Comment: So my [original comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867520/how-to-copy-the-root-folder-using-powershell/25869345?noredirect=1#comment40479712_25867520) covers this then... In which case the next question is where is the "latest folder" you refer to located?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t make it so complicated, just specify the source path for `Copy-Item` by using the output of your selection:

```
copy (ls $localPath | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 1) $DestinationPath -Recurse
```